# I don't know why ip_hdr(skb) return NULL

Tags: c, ip, netfilter

```
static unsigned int main_hook(unsigned int hooknum , struct sk_buff *skb , const struct net_device *in , const struct net_device *out, int (*okfn)(struct sk_buff*))
{    
        int i=0;
        struct iphdr *iph = ip_hdr(skb);
        unsigned long saddr = 0 , daddr = 0;
        unsigned long snet = 0; //dnet =0;
        int dst_cnt=0 , src_cnt=0;

        //printk("netfilter called\n");

        //down(&sema);
        Netfilter_Execute++;

        saddr = iph->saddr;
        daddr = iph->daddr;
```

when I execute this module program, the linux shut down and reboot.
When I test the program, `iph` is null so `saddr = iph->saddr and daddr = iph->daddr` was wrong.

I don't know why `iph = ip_hdr(skb)` returns `NULL`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem may be depend on which hook you use,
you have to mind where your hook place related to the kernel routing module.

Let me show you these 2 examples

1. If you use

   > NF_IP_LOCAL_OUT

   The packet that you receive in your hook doesn't go throw the Routing module in the kernel so it will not have a header
2. If you use

   > NF_IP_LOCAL_IN

   The packet will go throw the Routing module but the Routing module will remove the header of the packet and route it to an internal process

Comment: i use NF_INET_PRE_ROUTING

Answer (score 1):

try:
instead of `struct iphdr *iph = ip_hdr(skb);`, type `struct iphdr *iph = (struct iphdr *)skb_network_header(skb);`